# What could possibly cause the stress shift in adverbs ending in -arily compared to adjectives ending in -ary?

Tags: adjectives, pronunciation, adverbs, suffixes, stress

While adjectives ending in *-ary* (British English /əri/, American English /eri/) never have stress on the second last syllable (the /e/ in AmE, and obviously the /ə/ in BrE), their derivative adverbs have stress on that syllable (as the third last one of course, because of /li/). Here are some adjectives and adverbs. Wherever there are two transcriptions, the first one is BrE and the second AmE:

- **arbitrary**: /ˈɑːbɪtrəri/ /ˈɑːrbətreri/ > **arbitrarily** /ˈɑːbɪtrərəli/ /ˌɑːrbəˈtrerəli/
- **momentary**: /ˈməʊməntəri/ /ˈmoʊmənteri/ > **momentarily** /ˈməʊməntərəli/ /ˌmoʊmənˈterəli/
- **necessary**: /ˈnesəseri/ > **necessarily**: /ˌnesəˈserəli/
- **primary**: /ˈpraɪməri/ /ˈpraɪmeri/ > **primarily**: /praɪˈmerəli/
- **summary**: /ˈsʌməri/ > **summarily**: /ˈsʌmərəli/ /səˈmerəli/
- **voluntary**: /ˈvɒləntəri/ /ˈvɑːlənteri/ > **voluntarily**: /ˌvɒlənˈterəli/ /ˌvɑːlənˈterəli/

The entry for *-arily* in the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* notes this stress shift is more common in AmE, although it is increasingly common in BrE as well.

Since the adverb-creating suffix *-ly* isn't really known for heavily influencing the pronunciations of adjectives (think of literally any other types of adjectives-adverb pairs where this stress shift does not occur), what is so unique about *-ary* adjectives and *-arily* adverbs?

Could it be that at some point, when a word becomes too long, even a strongly established rule can be broken in order to make it easier to pronounce? I can sort of see why this stress shift is necessary, because saying *necessarily* with the stress pattern of the *necessary* is a bit difficult for my nonnative ability. In BrE, possible difficulty could arise because we have three consecutive weak, neutral and unstressed vowels, as in /ərəli/. Or perhaps /rəli/ is difficult to say because /r/ and /l/ are too similar as [liquid consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_consonant), which are known to be easily confused in other languages (e.g. Portuguese *branco* compared to Spanish *blanco*).

Or, maybe there's a prosodic reason. For example, *necessarily* would constitute quite a ridiculous [foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_(prosody)), *NE-ces-sa-ri-ly*, with **only** the first of five syllables being stressed. But if an additional stress is added, the word is effectively broken down into something simpler (?), two small feet instead of one big one, meaning *NE-ces-SA-ri-ly* consisting of a trochee and a dactyl?

Comment: I'm not a phonologist, but I would suspect that the secondary stress on _-ar-_ would become primary and swap with the first syllable when the _-ly_ gets added. Dunno if there's a cute name like Antepenultimate Stress Upgrade for it, but that's at least the result, if not the cause.